# R Vapply with IF & String Output

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to replace my for loop with a vapply due to efficiency. I have 1 column (x) with values that I want to ID which quartile they fall into. Then paste that into another column. Initially my for loop was...

```
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  if(x[i]> quantile(x,.75,na.rm=TRUE)) {
    y[i]="Q4"
  } else if (x[i]> quantile(x,.5,na.rm=TRUE)){
    y[i]="Q3"
  } else if (x[i]> quantile(x,.25,na.rm=TRUE)){
    y[i]="Q2"
  } else if (x[i]>=0) {
    y[i] = "Q1"
  } else (y[i]="")
}
```

And this worked great! but I read an article that discussed how more efficient vlook up is. So, I played around and tried the code...

```
vapply(quantiletable, function(x,y)
  if(x> quantile(x,.75,na.rm=TRUE)) {
    y="Q4"
  } else if (x> quantile(x,.5,na.rm=TRUE)){
    y="Q3"
  } else if (x> quantile(x,.25,na.rm=TRUE)){
    y="Q2"
  } else if (x>=0) {
    y = "Q1"
  } else (y="")
,rep(0,2))
```

This is my first attemp at vapply, so I'm sure I'm missing something/not allowed to do something.

The error I get is...
Warning message:

```
In FUN(X[[i]]) : argument length is > 1 and only the first element will be used (4 times)
Error: values must be length 2, but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code is slow because you recalculate that quantile for every item and for every condition, not so much because of the for loop. The quantiles are constant - you should calculate them once before doing your binning.

Comment: As for the binning, `vapply` will give you a marginal speed up compared to a for loop. Real efficiency gains can be had by vectorizing, e.g., using the vectorized `ifelse()` instead of the one-item-at-a-time `if(){} else{}`. But binning is a very common task, the function `cut()` does what you want. I believe what you want is `y = cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, quantile(x, c(.25, .5, .75), na.rm = TRUE), Inf), labels = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"))`

Comment: Beat me by 2 seconds :-) (exactly the same code)

Comment: Do you have a good dupe? I'd like to close, but I'm surprised I'm not finding an R-FAQ

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm thank you so much!